# Does LINQ deferred execution occur when rendering the view, or earlier?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, deferred-execution

Given a very basic LINQ that is returned to a MVC view, at what exact point does the deferred execution fire?

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _fooService.GetAll();
    return View(model);
}
```

In the model:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {    
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Bar</td>
   </tr>
}
```

The query is not executed when we call `_fooService.GetAll()` of course, but is deferred to some later point - but at which exact point is it executed?

- The `return View(model);` statement in the controller (doesn't look like it)?
- The `@foreach (var item in Model)` line in the view?
- The first time the `@item.Bar` line in the view is hit?
- Something else that occurs in between `return View(model);` and the view being rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx) addresses this question under the deferred query execution section (emphasis mine).

> In a query that returns a sequence of values, the query variable
>   itself never holds the query results and only stores the query
>   commands. Execution of the query is deferred **until the query variable
>   is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop**...

That narrows down the answer to options 2 and 3.

`foreach` is just syntactic sugar, underneath the compiler re-writes that as a while loop.  There's a pretty thorough explanation of what happens [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).  Basically your loop will end up looking something like this

```
{
  IEnumerator<?> e = ((IEnumerable<?>)Model).GetEnumerator();
  try
  { 
    int m;  // this is inside the loop in C# 5
    while(e.MoveNext())
    {
      m = (?)e.Current;
      // your code goes here
    }
  }
  finally
  { 
    if (e != null) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Enumerator is advanced before it reaches your code inside the loop, so slightly before you get to `@item.Bar`.  That only leaves option 2, the `@foreach (var item in Model)` line (though technically that line doesn't exist after the compiler is done with your code).

I'm not sue if the query will execute on the call to `GetEnumerator()` or on the first call to `e.MoveNext()`.

---

As @pst points out in the comments, there are other ways to trigger execution of a query, such as by calling `ToList`, and it may not internally use a `foreach` loop.  MSDN documentation sort of addresses this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx):

> The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if
>   it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated.
>   **Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable
>   object to be executed.** The definition of "executing an expression
>   tree" is specific to a query provider. For example, it may involve
>   translating the expression tree to an appropriate query language for
>   the underlying data source. **Queries that do not return enumerable
>   results are executed when the Execute method is called.**

My understanding of that is an attempt to enumerate the expression will cause it to execute (be it through a `foreach` or some other way).  How exactly that happens will depend on the implementation of the provider.

Answer (score 5):

The query execution (I assume GetAll returns iqueryable) will be deferred into the view, and will be unwrapped on the foreach line, because that is the first place where you start iterating over the collection.

**Update**
For anybody interested, here's "proof". Create a class like this:

```
public class DiagnosticCollection<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
{
    public new Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        Debug.Print("Collection Unwrap");
        return base.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Test it in your view like this:

```
@model PlayMvc.Models.DiagnosticCollection<string>
@{System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Before foreach");}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("After foreach");
    @item
}
```

Comment: I just want to mention that you should probably force execution in the controller.  This will prevent problems in the future like accidentally enumerating it multiple times.

Comment: I don't think its such a great idea - what if the view does not need all of the data, eg if its a grid with paging: if you force execution you lose the benefits of that paging

Comment: This is something to be careful when working with EntityFramework. I first noticed this behavior because objects were getting lazy loaded in the view, which not only I didn't need, but was actually breaking certain business rules. I ended up adding a filter to detach objects from the state manager after controller execution completed to ensure that deferred execution in the view would return null on the lazy loading properties and not issue additional db calls. Something to watch out for...

Answer (score 2):

As a point of clarification, LINQ to SQL/Entity Framework evaluate the LINQ query expressions when the GetEnumerator is called. This is used under the covers by foreach, thus while it appears that deferred execution waits until the foreach happens, it is actually the GetEnumerator that foreach uses that really is the key execution point.

Comment: +1 first answer to say at what exact point the execution occurs

Answer (score -2):

The work is deferred until it **needs** to be done. In your example, the query will run when it tries to get a value for `item`.

Comment: Your answer is a little misleading because it suggests that writing a loop like this `foreach( var item in Model ){ }` would not execute the query (since `item` is ever accessed).